# Is there a way to be less random than ORDER BY RAND to increase speed?

Tags: mysql

I run this query 5 times, 5 seconds apart, on a table of 500,000 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `apps` WHERE dev_name = '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

I'd like to get 50 rows that have a 90-95% chance of being unique. The query takes 10 seconds right now. I'd rather get it lower and have a smaller chance of being random.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AND RAND() >= 0.90
```

(or 0.95 if you like) in your WHERE clause.

Comment: That'll be faster than `ORDER BY RAND`?

Comment: Yes, but not very random at all. The chance of getting an entry back that comes late in the natural order of the table is very small that way.

Comment: @luksch Why? It should select any row with the same probability.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to study [Fetching Random Rows from a Table](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random), as highlighted in [here in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast). Another great article can be found [here](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/).